# A type of initializer?

Tags: c++, struct

In the following program `a` is directly initialized with temporary:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B{ };

struct A
{
    A(int, B){ std::cout << "A(int, B)" << std::endl; }
};

A a({4,B()});

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3cf4e8f1d44d59b)**

But what the Standard says is `N3797::8.5/17 [dcl.init]`:

> — If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> — If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-
>   unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of
>   the destination, constructors are considered.
>
> — Otherwise (i.e., *for the remaining copy-initialization cases*),
>   user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source
>   type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used)
>   to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4,
>   and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3).

[...]

I don't understand what rule is applicabl to that case? Why is the temporary created and what is the type of initializer-expression `{4,B()}`?

Comment: The braced-init-list does not have a type. List initialization is occurring here, first a temporary instance of `A` is created and then `a` is copy constructed from that.

Comment: @Praetorian Why is copy? I thought `a` is direct-initialized with temporary.

Comment: @Praetorian In any wasy, couldn't you provide a reference describes the initialization in that case?

Comment: It is direct initialized, the constructor chosen for that is the copy constructor. You can verify that yourself by explicitly deleting the copy constructor. And if I was willing to dig through the standard right now, I'd post an answer :)

Comment: @Praetorian Technically, the one chosen is the move constructor :)

Comment: It's the first bullet ("If the initialization is direct-initialization..."). I assume you know how `A a(1);` works. Then replace `1` with a *braced-init-list* and consider how overload resolution to select the applicable constructor for direct-initialization is performed in that case. 13.3.3.1.4 and 13.3.3.1.5 are relevant.

Comment: *what is the type of initializer-expression {4,B()}* - [A braced initializer has no type!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU&list=UUMlGfpWw-RUdWX_JbLCukXg#t=1792).